# Usage permissions for AppHooks in DjangoCMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm registering a new custom AppHook in DjangoCMS (v.3.5.3):

```
@apphook_pool.register
class CustomAppHook(CMSApp):
    name = _("CustomAppHook")

    def get_urls(self, page=None, language=None, **kwargs):
        return ["customapp.urls"]
```

I want to hide this app hook in the dropdown menu in the extended page settings. Only superusers should see and use it. To exclude the "extended page settings" for other users/groups is no option here...

Is there another decorator to use?

There exists the `permissions = True` attribute in the **CMSApp** class. But this says: *"if set to true, apphook inherits permissions from the current page"*. Not excactly what I want/need.

Comment: Do you mean that you want users to be able to add apps to pages, just that this one is only available to superusers?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: I don't believe the CMS has that level of granularity to the permission system.